# Clone latest committed files on Git Repo

Tags: php, git

I want to clone the last committed files via Git. I tried the --depth 1 parameter. But the all project was cloned. I want to download only the last edited files because the project size is too high.

The command I tried;

```
git clone --depth 1 https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST/PATH
```

I want to clone last edited and updated files. I don't want to go back to the previous committed files. I will analyze the last edited files with SonarQube. I don't want to clone the all project for this. And : I'm using exec with PHP to run commands.

How can I clone only the last edited files? Thank you.

Comment: So, if you want to get updated code of the repo, I believe it is `git pull` ?

Comment: @yusuf  why don't you login into your GIT account and download the last committed file, very simple if you just want to download the last committed file

Comment: Why dont you `git pull` ?

Comment: I believe `pull` should suffice your purpose.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli - The OP asks about cloning the last committed files, not to undo them.

Comment: Friends, I want to clone last edited and updated files. I don't want to go back to the previous committed files. I will analyze the last edited files with SonarQube. I don't want to clone the all project for this. And : I'm using exec with PHP to run commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just download a couple of files from a remote git repository. In order for git to restore a file, it must have all the data of the repository available. So unfortunately you will have to download the whole repository. If you would like to see which files have been changed, you can then run `git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT HEAD` to receive a list of modified files.

Comment: *[g]it tracks and saves changes made to files. So in order for git to reconstruct a file, it must also know how to apply all changes made in history.* You described RCS/CVS/Subversion/Mercurial but not git. git stores entire working directory, not changes. It doesn't need to apply changes, it just restores files from saved blobs. [See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version-control_software#Technical_information) how different VCSen store files: there're 2 major ways: changesets and snapshots. RCS/CVS/Subversion/hg store changesets; git stores snapshots.

Comment: You're right, @phd. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git archive --format=tar --remote=<repository URL> HEAD | tar xf -
```

Also, if your browse remote repository using some web interface like Gitweb or GitHub, then it may have 'snapshot' feature with it and you can also download the newest version.